How do I get a workflow to rerun when the container is updated?
I have several repos that use the "latest" of a container in the GitHub Actions workflows. However, they don't rerun the workflow when the "latest" changes. For example, https://github.com/gridlabd-tutorials/lesson-1 uses the container lfenergy/arras:latest. I would like the workflow .github/workflows/main.yml to rerun when the container is updated by the maintainer.
How do I set up the workflow so that happens automatically? I didn't find anything in the docs to suggest how that might be done.

There's no built-in trigger for that. And please don't approve that suggested edit; there's a whole fleet of accounts trying to farm reputation by suggesting utterly inane tags.
